# DateTool velocity month

Tags: velocity

It's a question very basic, I know, but I have a little difficulties with that :

I would like to display in velocity the date with the object DateTool but only the month and the year :

In this moment, I know :

```
Vos détails de rémunération pour le mois de $date.format($c.time)
```

displays the date entirely but I would like only the month and the year.

I am looking the API but I haven't found yet.

If you have a suggestion.

Ale.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a pattern such as:

```
$date.format('M',$myDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [documentation of the `DateTool` class](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html), you'll see several `format` methods. The [most basic one](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html#format%28java.lang.Object%29) takes only a date as a parameter, which will use the format configured globally for the date tool. The [next one](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) also takes a format string as a parameter, which can either be one of the known keywords, or a formatting string corresponding to [the standard Java datetime formatting options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (there's a more thorough description along with examples here). So you might want to use something like:

```
Vos détails de rémunération pour le mois de $date.format('MMMM yyyy', $c.time)
```

Make sure the system's locale is set to French as well, otherwise you'll have to place a `$locale` variable in the context with the `Locale.FRENCH` value and use the [3-params method](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/1.4/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Locale%29) to get the correct name of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, I resolve the trick ! My solution is :

```
<p class="noMarTop headSection"><span style="padding-top:10px;">Vos détails de rémunération pour le mois de $date.format(' MMMMM  yyyy',$c.time) </span></p>
```

to display the month and the year completely.

> Vos détails de rémunération pour le mois de juillet 2009

Thanks for the links.

Ale.